# writing a jquery function to reuse a formula

Tags: javascript, jquery, formula, reusability

I have a function that does some stuff and one thing it does is calculates height/width and applies css top/left for centering. Instead of rewriting the formula more than once, I want to be able to reuse it and pass arguments through it.

I have:

```
loading.css({
    top: (wrapper.height() - loading.outerHeight()) / 2 + 'px',
    left: (wrapper.width() - loading.outerWidth()) / 2 + 'px'
});
```

I want to be able to reuse those 2 formulas and also replace `loading` with other registered elements.

I have no idea what I'm doing and I've tried several things which failed...

I want to be able to call it through something like `loading._center();`

---

When the function runs, it appends the loading div and calculates the absolute positioning top and left using the code above. I wanted it to stay centered when the window resizes, so I basically duplicated the code above and wrapped it with a `$(window).resize` function.

When an error div is shown, since the height/width dimensions are different, I'm calculating top and left again with a similar code. Instead of duplicating the `element.css({top: [...], left: [...]})`, I just want to do something like...

```
_center = function() {
    var context = $(this);
    context.css({
        top: (wrapper.height() - context.outerHeight()) / 2 + 'px',
        left: (wrapper.width() - context.outerWidth()) / 2 + 'px'
    });
};

loading._center();
```

---

I was close. I forgot to return the calculation.. I now have:

```
_center = function($this) {
    $this.css({
        top: (wrapper.height() - $this.outerHeight()) / 2 + 'px',
        left: (wrapper.width() - $this.outerWidth()) / 2 + 'px'
    });
};

_center(loading);
```

Comment: give more examples of how you would reuse those functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could provide a function for the 2nd argument:

```
loading.css('top', function(index, oldValue) {
  return (wrapper.height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2 + 'px';
});

loading.css('left', function(index, oldValue) {
  return (wrapper.width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2 + 'px';
});
```

Here's the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) of the .css().

Answer (score 0):

You can register it as a jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn._center = function(wrapper) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).css({
            top: ($(wrapper).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2 + 'px',
            left: ($(wrapper).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2 + 'px'    
        });
    });
};
```

and call it like this:

```
var wrapper = $("#someDiv");
$(".foo, .bar")._center(wrapper);
```

See [authoring jQuery plugins.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Comment: I thought I read somewhere about plugins that separate everything clutter up the namespace or something.

Comment: @gavsiu - You should read the section on namespacing in the doc linked above.